# Errno 2 when pip install from github

Tags: git, github, package

I am trying to install this package (https://github.com/lseman/pylspm) from github using `pip install git+https://github.com/lseman/pylspm.git` via the terminal accessed from Anaconda Navigator (system is Windows 10, 64 bit). When I run it I get this error:

```
C:\Users\atran>pip install git+https://github.com/lseman/pylspm.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/lseman/pylspm.git
  Cloning https://github.com/lseman/pylspm.git to c:\users\atran\appdata\local\temp\pip-01gbtmkf-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\atran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\atran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-01gbtmkf-build\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\atran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-01gbtmkf-build\
```

I've tried a few things including installing reinstalling, and updating pip, git, setup, ez_setup. None of these seemed to help.

Any ideas on what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `setup.py` at https://github.com/lseman/pylspm. There is `setup.py` at https://github.com/lseman/pylspm/tree/master/pylspm but it's wrong (it names `src` as `package_dir` but there is no `src` subdirectory anywhere in the repository).

Resume: the repository is full of bugs and not pip-installable. I think the only way to use it is to clone it and manually copy to `site-packages`. But I would be very afraid of code like this.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, when I get the fatal error, it is because the directory already exists and has a .git directory within it. You will need to delete this directory (`pylsm` in your case) before you use `git clone https://github.com/lseman/pylspm.git` again.

Comment: Deleted pylsm in the directory and ran "pip install git+https://github.com/lseman/pylspm.git", but the issue still persists unfortunately.